# {{ form.object }} in Django UpdateView

Tags: django, django-templates

According to the docs `self.object` exists for [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)

Template:

```
{% block content %}

<p>
    {{ form.object.some_foreign_key }}
</p>

<form method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

But `form.object` does not exist:

> Failed: Undefined template variable 'form.object' in '/foo/bar_form.html'

Why does `form.object` not exist in the template?

Comment: what does make you think form.object should exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem you are confusing `UpdateView` class attribute `object` with injected template context `form` instance

Form instance is set in same way as it would be set if you did function based view and `self.object` is set as `form.instance`

From `ModelFormMixin`

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """Return the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    if hasattr(self, 'object'):
        kwargs.update({'instance': self.object})
    return kwargs
```

Furthermore you can check for instance get() method in `ProcessFormView` and go up through implementations of `get_context_data` in `FormMixin`

Comment: OK, instead of `{{ form.object.some_foreign_key }}` I use `{{ object.some_foreign_key }}` and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest that you use form.instance as this way you can reuse same templates no matter if you use class or form based views

Answer (score 1):

That's in the case you want to access the `object` from a python class, if you want to access a specific field from a template, just use `form.some_foreign_key`.

If you want to access the instance itself, you can use `form.instance`.